# Javascript timer How to replace digits with images?

Tags: javascript

Hello how can I replace digits in following javascript timer with respective images. ie 0 with dig1.png, 1 with dig2.png, 3 with dig3. png.....colon(:) with colo.png.
    00:23:01 ==>> [image]

```
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;


function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
TotalSeconds = Time;

UpdateTimer()
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function Tick() {
if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {
doSubmit();
document.getElementById("timeisup").innerHTML = "Time is up response.";
return;
}

TotalSeconds -= 1;
UpdateTimer()
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}


function UpdateTimer() {
Timer.innerHTML = TotalSeconds;
}

function UpdateTimer() {
var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
Seconds -= Days * 86400;

var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
Seconds -= Minutes * (60);


var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" 
+ LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)


Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
}


function LeadingZero(Time) {

return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;

}
```

And here is the html markup that shows the timer...

```
<span id="timer"style="font-weight: bold;"></span><script
type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", 7200);</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using some cool font instead. There is lot of digital fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to create the images first and leave them in place

```
<img id="d0" src="dig0.png">
<img id="d1" src="dig0.png">
<img src="col.png">
<img id="d2" src="dig0.png">
<img id="d3" src="dig0.png">
<img src="col.png">
<img id="d4" src="dig0.png">
<img id="d5" src="dig0.png">
```

and then just update image `src` from javascript:

```
var digits = [document.getElementById("d0"),
              document.getElementById("d1"),
              document.getElementById("d2"),
              document.getElementById("d3"),
              document.getElementById("d4"),
              document.getElementById("d5")];

function setTime(hh, mm, ss) {
    digits[0].src = "dig" + Math.floor(hh / 10) + ".png";
    digits[1].src = "dig" + (hh % 10) + ".png";
    digits[2].src = "dig" + Math.floor(mm / 10) + ".png";
    digits[3].src = "dig" + (mm % 10) + ".png";
    digits[4].src = "dig" + Math.floor(ss / 10) + ".png";
    digits[5].src = "dig" + (ss % 10) + ".png";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Old fashion and not Optimal**:
First, create the HTML DOM objects:

```
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.className = "style here";
    //image.style can come here ...
    image.src = "Path/to/image/here";
```

Or pre-populate `image` with

```
    <image src="path/to/image" id="imageId like ie0">
```

And Append them to the div you want in your Tick function:

```
 var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent div ID");
 parentDiv.appendChild(image);
```

**Modern way of doing it**:

Include CSS in your code. You can add pretty styles and no worries for the images as it will be slow and somewhat inconsistent. See a live example with open source code is here: [Minimal  Digital Clock with CSS](http://cssdeck.com/labs/minimal-css3-digital-clock)